# Making SMS sound and other notifications play in speaker with headphones inserted

Tags: notifications, audio, ringtone, speaker

I would like to be able to go to sleep with headphones plugged into my S4 so that I can listen to podcasts, but then there is the problem that I don't hear SMS messages or calls during the night, because the notification sounds are played in the headset also.

What I need is that every incoming SMS message and phonecall notification are played through the speaker and not the headphones. It is not a problem if this causes the podcast or music in the headphones to stop while the notification is playing in the speaker.

So is there an app or other method that fixes this?

I have checked Soundabout, but it seems that it is not able to force notifications to speakers, only phonecalls.

Edit:
There is a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8286/with-headphones-plugged-in-set-incoming-call-ringtone-to-play-through-speaker?rq=1), but that one is limited to phonecalls, and it seems that there is a difference to routing the sound for phonecalls, to other notifications.

Comment: Your question will do better here if you focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than asking us to help you find an app which you think will solve your problem.

Comment: Well, to be honest i believe my question was pretty focused on the problem i was trying to solve, even though i mentioned that I except that an app perhaps existed for my specific need. Or?

Did change the subject field of the thread however.

Comment: I would tend to agree, but it seems that there are some people around here who see "is there an app that" and immediately reach for the "close" button. You might also want to have a look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I get more where you are coming from now. Still I think my use case is probably not specific to only me.